# Can I develop Cross-Platform Applications in Visual Studio? (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, cross-platform

If I only write code that would work on all systems, and use cross-platform libraries, can I use Visual Studio:

- to Write Cross-Platform Code?
- to Compile Cross-Platform Code?

And how would I go about compiling it cross platform? I'm guessing some make-file wizardry.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean by all systems? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Louis93 All mayor systems. If I were to write a very simple application just printing Hello World in the console, would it compile for all platforms?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Visual Studio IDE to write Cross-Platform code, but to compile for a non-windows target you'll need a different toolchain. I'm not so sure if VS supports applying a different toolchain on a project, doubt it.

I'd recommend [Eclipse CDT](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) (which in turn supports compiling projects with the M$ toolchain).

Answer (score 0):

Making OS portable C++ code is pretty easy if you just intend to use ISO compatible C++ compilers, ISO Standard C++ and [libraries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) & [STL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library).

The problem is that most OS's have differences on data types, defines, API's for non-standard libraries, etc. A whole suite of GNU tools have been made to solve this:

- [Autoconf](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/)
- [Automake](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/)
- [Libtool](http://www.gnu.org/software/libtool/)

Also, Visual Studio don't use makefile's out-of-the-box, you can use makefile's on Windows but then you lose all the Visual Studio integration. We use standard Visual Studio solutions when compiling on Windows and makefiles for Linux and UNIX.

Comment: You can integrate makefiles into visual studio, but your project and build can be pretty orthogonal in that case (you maintain the makefiles without much help from the IDE)